# What files in an Xcode iOS project should I tell Mercurial to ignore?

Tags: xcode, version-control, mercurial

When programming an iOS application, there are many files Xcode deals with. I've noticed when I'm programming, the `.xcodeproj` file is always being modified. What I'm wondering is **whether or not the `.xcodeproj` file should be ignored by Mercurial or not**. Also, are there any other files that should be ignored by Mercurial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually ignore these files:

```
.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib
build/
*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*.project.xcworkspace
*.xcuserdata
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
```

Comment: I have found that the .xcodeproj changes too much to warrant version control.  Instead, I check in a compressed .xcodeproj and ignore *.xcodeproj.  The compressed file I commit along with a README to explain that you need to extract that file to get the latest project settings.