# What do all the changes to .xuserstate and .xcscheme files represent?

Tags: git, xcode4

Whenever I check in changes to my OS X app Xcode 4 projects into git, a lot of lines of files like these get changed with practically every commit

```
 .../UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate                 | 3927 ++++++++++++++++++++
 .../test.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Deployment.xcscheme |   72 +
 .../test.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Hush.xcscheme       |   76 +
 .../xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
```

Is this stuff necessary to put under version control? The changes to *.xcuserstate clutter up the output of `git log -p` so much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a post that describes what can safely be put in the ignore files:

[xcodeproj under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683513/xcodeproj-under-version-control/4684751#4684751)

It looks like you can safely ignore some of them.

Here are a few others posts:

- [What files in an Xcode iOS project should I tell Mercurial to ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5923503/275354)
- [SVN ignore pattern with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474523/svn-ignore-pattern-with-xcode-4/6546289#6546289)
- [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects/49488#49488)