# What is the plist file and do I need to check it in?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am wondering what the purpose is of the *.plist files? Do I need to check them into the source control, or are they generated automatically?

Comment: Which plist file? What's it called?

Comment: xcschememanagement.pinfo

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770472/what-do-all-the-changes-to-xuserstate-and-xcscheme-files-represent

Answer (score 3):

Purpose:

- A great way to store dictionary data that does not change during
  runtime is in a .plist file. If you want to organize some data
  hierarchically you can store it in .plist file

[According to the Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html),

> A property list is a representation of a hierarchy of objects that can
>   be stored in the file system and reconstituted later. Property lists
>   give applications a lightweight and portable way to store small
>   amounts of data. They are hierarchies of data made from specific types
>   of objects—they are, in effect, an object graph. Property lists are
>   easy to create programmatically and are even easier to serialize into
>   a representation that is persistent. Applications can later read the
>   static representation back into memory and recreate the original
>   hierarchy of objects. Both Cocoa Foundation and Core Foundation have
>   APIs related to property list serialization and deserialization.

Do I need to check it into the source control?

- Yes you need to check it into the source control.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the `info.plist` file it is where the bundle ID, version number, and loads of other info about the app is stored. If that info isn't important to you then it doesn't need to be in your repo, but the smart money is on keeping it under version control.

Apple has info about the what the file is for and what the various keys are if you Google `info.plist` you will get all the information you could possibly need about it.

Comment: I mean xcschememanagement.pinfo